# Net Core: access to appsettings.json values from Autofac Module

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac, autofac-module

AspNet core app

1) Autofac module like that

```
public class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      //Register my components. Need to access to appsettings.json values from here
    }
}
```

2) Module from step№1 registered into `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
    }
```

How to access to `appsettings.json` values from `AutofacModule`? I need that for create my objects inside `AutofacModule` and using it for DI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to change step №2

```
        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //get settigns as object from config
        var someSettings= Configuration.GetSection(typeof(SomeSettings).Name).Get<SomeSettings>();                                                    
        //put settings into module constructor 
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule(someSettings));
    }
```

I don't know is "best practise" way or not, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

So currently trying this as well.

First thing is to get the necessary nuget packages, and add them as using statements at the top of your class.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Configuration;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

In your Program.cs Main or Startup.cs...

```
public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

Main() or Startup()
{

// Add the configuration to the ConfigurationBuilder.
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
var configurationModule = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());

containerBuilder.RegisterModule(configurationModule);

//register anything else you need to...

Container = containerBuilder.Build();
}
```

This will register the configuration module into your autoFac container, after which you can then use constructor injection to pass this round...

```
public class YourController
{
    private readonly IContainer _config;

    public YourController(IContainer configuration)
    {
        // Use IContainer instance
        _config = configuration;
    }
```

Hope that helps somewhat, if you get any further a different way then please share.

Comment: @Cris Could you provide an example how to inject  IConfiguration based on your response above. Because in mycase RegisterModule had no effect.

Comment: @Trinitron same. I think maybe I misunderstand the use of `IContainer` here, too. Shouldn't it be `IConfiguration`??