# Can Autofac read app.settings file in a type safe manner like .Net core?

Tags: c#, autofac, .net-4.7.2

Using .Net core , with ConfigurationBuilder ,I can read a Json file ( app.settings) into a typed structure:

```
var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
var config = configBuilder.Build();    
services.Configure<MyOptions>(config);
```

So now, it's Injectable via `IOptions<MyOptions>`

But Looking at Autofac documentation/example - I didn't find a similar flow.

**Question:**

Besides writing it manually, can Autodac read JSON files and make them Injectable, Just like `IOptions`?

*BTW I'm using .Net 4.7*

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888812/net-core-access-to-appsettings-json-values-from-autofac-module/47142119

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: You could use same configuration framework. load the JSON and inject it into your container.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks. This is what I did. I will leave this question here for others.

Comment: @Nkosi BTW would you use autofac in .net core ?

Comment: It is usable. I see no immediate reason not to. I tend to use the default .net core dependency injection as a base DI platform which would also allow for me to swap out parts if I wanted to use a 3rd party container as the backing provider. I like the modular design of .net core for that.